# Mobius Form 3 Errors on 2sxc 10.25?

Tags: razor, 2sxc, dnn9

I have a DNN 9.04.04 site with Porto 5.x (latest). Otherwise no other modules installed much installed (except Live Slider which came w Porto). So I installed 2sxc 10.25. Then added Content App... errors, but I fixed both; a) had to add koi.json and b) web.config was missing the System.Web.Helpers binding redirect for v3.0.x. Those seem common to me now. Mentioning because maybe they are related to where I got stuck?

I installed Mobius 3.0 and after Googling for the error and finding anything, decided to ask here before maybe reporting it as a bug? If it matters, I let 2sxc install Mobius for me. I think I chose just the FAQ and Mobius. After install, choosing apps, both show the newer icons and Mobius clearly has the v3 in the upper right corner. The app installed ok, but then adding it to the page in the usual way results in this View/template error:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The webpage at '/Portals/0/2sxc/Mobius 
Forms/_Contact Form.cshtml' must derive from SexyContentWebPage. at 
ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.InitWebpage() in 
C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 142 at 
ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Init() in 
C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 44 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Init(ICmsBlock cmsBlock, Purpose purpose, ILog parentLog) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 75 at 
ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.CmsBlock.GetRenderingEngine(Purpose renderingPurpose) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\CmsBlock_Render.cs:line 127 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.CmsBlock.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\CmsBlock_Render.cs:line 56
```

***Additional info added 2/2/2020:***

There is no coding or modifications here. I just installed DNN latest, 2sxc latest, and then used 2sxc UI to add Mobius 3. Errors (above) appear immediately once Mobius is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I can't be sure about, you seem to be missing the web.config in the 2sxc folder. Best compare it with a working solution.

Comment: If you mean \DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\web.config, it is there. Looks to be original and matches the same in another project. Can you elaborate on what you see/suspect? I am happy to check more things and run it down, but not really sure what I am looking for at this point.

Comment: Every razor page inherits from a base class. You can specify which - for example if you want to use newer features in 2sxc 10.25 - see https://r.2sxc.org/RazorComponent. Otherwise it uses what is specified in the web.config, or the default. 
Up until 10.25, we never recommended an @inherits, so it always inherited the SexyContentWebPage - as specified in web.config. If it's not inheriting from that, something must be interfering or configs are missing.

Comment: There is no coding or modifications here. I just installed DNN latest, 2sxc latest, and then used 2sxc UI to add Mobius 3. Errors (above) appear immediately once Mobius is on the page.

Comment: Do you have the same issue on another app - or just Mobius? And/or on another DNN or another portal?

Comment: Any progress on this?